# Playing one video while another is buffering

Tags: android, streaming, video-streaming, media-player, buffering

I have two videos. Video A is present on the device while video B needs to be streamed off the internet. My goal is to play video A while video B starts buffering. As I understand it I need to create one MediaPlayer instance for each video. Then I can call prepareAsync() on both and start playing in onPrepared(). However, there seem to be some limitations in Android which together prevent this from working properly:

1) MediaPlayer can only start buffering after it has been provided a SurfaceView which is present on screen.

2) Only one MediaPlayer at a time can be connected to a SurfaceView.

3) There is only support for a single SurfaceView on screen.

One one phone I have managed to get two MediaPlayer instances to share one SurfaceView. On another I can get two SurfaceViews on screen at the same time. But as I understand it neither is officially supported by Android?

Am I doing something wrong? Has anyone else got this working?